# How can i send promotional email via rest or soap api?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketingcloudapi

I am working to create an environment where our client sends their promotional email. content of the email is dynamic. I am a little confused about which API we need to use to send promotional emails and which method Rest or Soap.

Soap Apis:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/emailsenddefinition.html
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/triggeredsend.html

Rest Api:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/messageDefinitionSends.html

Comment: Actually, you can use either one, REST or SOAP, for triggered sends - up to you which one is easier for you to implement

Comment: i am actually confuse in soap methods triggersend vs emailsenddefinition.

Comment: It’s this one: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/creating_a_triggered_send_definition.html

Comment: but Triggered Send Definition is used for transactional message not for promotional I believe?

Comment: You can configure either Transactional or Commercial send, in any of the methods you are listing. This is managed by the Send Classification of your email

Answer (score -1):

There are a few solutions that can be considered for this situation:

- Utilizing a data extension in Marketing Cloud and having your client
  enter data via the Data Extension APIs. This can then be followed by
  conducting bulk sends through an automation. This option is more
  efficient as the triggered send API's are not optimized for mass
  sends. However, it may require additional setup and integration with
  your client's data.
- Implementing a Triggered Send definition with a commercial send
  classification. This solution allows for the integration to proceed
  as desired, but it should be noted that using a high priority setting
  will consume 4 super messages.

Additionally, the transactional messaging API is not a viable option in this scenario as it can only be used for transactional send classifications.